# Video Meta problem (Ooyala to Facebook)

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

Evening,

I'm pretty much clueless at this point regarding playing videos on FB walls. I'm using Ooyala as a "Video CMS" and have enabled everything for FB sharing on their end. My code includes the following.

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns##">
     <head>
...
          <meta property="og:title" content="#video.title#">
          <meta property="og:description" content="#video.description#">
          <meta property="og:type" content="video">
          <meta property="og:image" content="http://ak.c.ooyala.com/BjOGpsMToPbHODr_JC75EC5lJqe2gGZE/promo109538534">
          <meta property="og:video" content="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=#url.watch#&autoplay=1">
          <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
          <meta property="og:video:width" content="396">
          <meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
          <meta property="og:site_name" content="AOPA">
     </head>
```

The file the code is in is a coldfusion file (hence the double #). When I paste a sample video link:

`http://www.aopa.org/aopalive/index.cfm?watch=VzbnZyMjoQKI1dI2Bwl-NeuiLToLxQpA`

Into a wall, FB recognizes it as a video. When I hit play, I can see it's loaded the Ooyala player, (they have a Mac-like "loading" circle), but no video is called.

Any ideas? I've seen almost every variant of "og:" tags out there, but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks!
-Mitch

P.S.: Facebook, you're still linking to "http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" in some of your SDK's.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add &keepEmbedCode=true to your queryString parameters. The meta video tag would then become -

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=#url.watch#&autoplay=1&keepEmbedCode=true">
```

Thanks,
Andrew

Andrew Spaulding | Senior Solutions Architect | Ooyala

www.flexdaddy.com

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

Thanks for the suggestion about the embed code, this still brought up the Ooyala player, but no video. After poking around (and looking at YouTube's source code for a single video), there needs to be some additional attributes added to the  tag.

The correct code is below.

Thanks, have a good weekend,
-Mitch

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="#video.title#"> 
<meta property="og:description" content="#video.description#">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ak.c.ooyala.com/BjOGpsMToPbHODr_JC75EC5lJqe2gGZE/promo109538534">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=#url.watch#&autoplay=1&keepembedCode=true">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="396">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="297">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="AOPA">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because my og:url was incorrectly formatted.

Once I set the og:url to be the link back to my original page (canonical) hosting the video, the video would play. Before this, it would show a play link, but when I click on it, it would not play anything.